# image drawable is not showing in imageview

Tags: android, image, svg, imageview, svg-android

i am working with svgs in my app. the issue is that my svgs are not loading when i create image view of size 1500px x 500px. i have to keep size of image view in pixels and it is fixed. but when i decrease the size of image view to 950px x 430px, the svg is showing properly. i am keeping svgs in my assets.

i am working on oppo and my device has android version 4.2

(P.S. i have checked the same svg with same dimensions of image view on other device and it is working alright)

please help

Comment: Can you post some code?  At exactly what size does the change from working to not-working happen?  Have you tried another SVG library to see if it is a bug in svg-android?